# report all roles that have some permission but not another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose you have this role id and permission id table.
I want to list all the roles that have permission 1,2 but are missing permission 3,4.
The roles can have other permissions, that should not matter. I only care to know permission 3,4 are missing from a role if that role has permission 1,2. So result for the test table below should be roleid 3.

I came up with a solution with lots of "in" and "not in". Asking to see if there's a better way. I'll post my solution later. I don't want to alter the thought process.

```
Declare @test table
(
 roleid int,
 permissionid int
)

insert into @test values(1,1)
insert into @test values(1,2)
insert into @test values(1,3)
insert into @test values(1,4)
insert into @test values(1,5)
insert into @test values(1,8)
insert into @test values(1,9)

insert into @test values(2,1)
insert into @test values(2,2)
insert into @test values(2,3)
insert into @test values(2,4)
insert into @test values(2,10)
insert into @test values(2,7)

insert into @test values(3,1)
insert into @test values(3,2)
insert into @test values(3,11)
insert into @test values(3,18)

insert into @test values(4,18)
insert into @test values(4,3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see, whether the given query works for you,

```
SELECT  ROLEID 
FROM    @TEST A 
WHERE   A.PERMISSIONID IN (1,2) 
AND     ROLEID NOT IN (SELECT ROLEID FROM @TEST WHERE PERMISSIONID IN (3,4) GROUP BY ROLEID)
GROUP   BY ROLEID
```

Comment: It does. Good solution.